# Pixelwise access to the fringe? Making a basic progressivescroll/metalscroll/VS-mapmode

Tags: fringe

Is there a way to create a fringe in emacs that can allow for arbitrary pixel-wise access from elisp?  Rather than 8x8 char-wise access that I think is the only option now.

What I'm looking for is a way to add small markers in the right fringe area to indicate where modified lines or other points of interest, like breakpoints/fly-check markers are in the buffer.

So these markers would be small and buffer relative, that is correspond to the vertical scroll-bar position.

Identical functionality can be seen in the Metalscroll, Progressive scroll or map-mode extensions to visual studio.

If there are any C patches for the emacs source that do something similar that anyone knows about I’d be really interested too.

Cheers,
  Rob